# C# Deleting a randomly file

Tags: c#, random

So I have this very interesting program in mind that when i press a button, it deletes a random file in a specific folder (for example, let's say the folder: "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test")
Let's say i have 20 files in this folder and each time I press the button it will delete 1 of those files randomly
Extemsions should not matter.

I need this for further research in C# and would have no clue where to start, nor have i found ANYTHING similiar on internet like this.
Feel free to help.

***And how would I make it Look/delete in Subfolders?***

Greetings
Luna

Comment: `and would have no clue where to start` start by getting a list of files. Then pick a random one. Then delete the one you picked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very simple task 4 lines of code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }

        private void buttonDeleteRundomFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Put all file names in a directory into array.
            string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test");

            // get a random file
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string fileName2Delete = array1[rnd.Next(1, array1.Count())];

            //delete that file
            File.Delete(fileName2Delete);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from looking in Subfolders it does exactly what i want!

Answer (score 1):

Figure out what kind of capabilities your program will need and research them to put together your program. I would research the following things and start programming:

- Getting all filenames in a directory
- Storing these filenames somehow
- Getting a random integer and picking the file to delete
- deleting a file with a given name

Always start by breaking your problem into the smallest parts possible and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

The person above (Aris Skam) is correct with the 1 exception of changing

```
// get a random file
Random rnd = new Random();
string fileName2Delete = array1[rnd.Next(1, array1.Count())];
```

to

```
// get a random file
Random rnd = new Random();
string fileName2Delete = array1[rnd.Next(0, array1.Count())];
```

changing the 1 to a 0 makes to so that every file can be removed whereas with a 1 it would leave a single folder that couldnt be deleted